# Cannot connect to Wi-Fi Ubuntu 18.04 (Secure boot disabled)

Tags: networking, wireless, hp, realtek-wireless

I cannot connect to Wi-Fi on my HP 15-DA0330TU Notebook. Everytime it says "No Wi-Fi adapter found". I had ran into this problem previously, but disabling secure boot in BIOS/EFI had helped then. Now, inspite of secure boot being disabled, it shows no wifi adapter found. 
Please help. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
~$  lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3 

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]

Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
Kernel modules: rtl8723de

~$ sudo modprobe rtl8723de && dmesg | grep rtl
 [sudo] password for user: 
 modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8723de': Unknown symbol in module,or unknown parameter (see dmesg)

~$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf
 cat: /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf: No such file or directory

~$ ls /etc/modprobe.d
alsa-base.conf                  blacklist-modem.conf
amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf  blacklist-oss.conf
blacklist-ath_pci.conf          blacklist-rare-network.conf
blacklist.conf                  dkms.conf
blacklist-firewire.conf         intel-microcode-blacklist.conf
blacklist-framebuffer.conf      iwlwifi.conf
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100226/discussion-on-question-by-aritri-cannot-connect-to-wi-fi-ubuntu-18-04-secure-bo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We see this in your paste results:

> rtlwifi-new, 0.6, 5.0.0-32-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff
>   between built and installed module!)

Let's remove the dkms version and see if the installed version works better. From the terminal:

```
sudo dkms remove rtlwifi-new/0.6 --all
```

You may also need to specify the antenna connection to use. Please do:

```
sudo -i
echo "options rtl8723de ant_sel=2"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf
exit
```

Reboot.

Comment: I get this following error while executing "sudo dkms remove  rtlwifi_new/0.6": Error! Invalid number of parameters passed. Usage: remove <module>/<module-version> --all or : remove <module>/<module-version> -k <kernal-version>

Comment: Sorry for my mis-step. Please add `--all` as I indicate in my edit above.

Comment: Now it says: Error! There are no instances of module: rtlwifi_new 0.6 located in the DKMS tree.

Comment: Does `sudo dkms status` confirm that? If you, proceed with the antenna step and reboot.

Comment: I proceeded with the antenna step and reboot but the sudo dkms status still shows rtlwifi-new, 0.6. The same thing basically. But when I try removing it with the command you said, it still says no instances of the module. What should I do?

Comment: I wonder if it is instead `rtlwifi-new` and not `rtlwifi_new` Please see my edit above. Sorry. Here is the source of my confusion: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new

Comment: Thanks a lot @chili555. I can't Thank you enough. This worked. Thanks!:)

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour Glad it's working.