# WiFi doesn't connect after machine sleeps or is suspended, connects only after reboot

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, realtek-wireless

I recently updated Ubuntu 18.04 to 18.04.4, on my HP 15-DA0330TU Notebook. Since then, the WiFi works fine only after a restart, but whenever the machine sleeps or disconnects the WiFi, upon trying to connect again it says "Activation of network connection failed." It shows the available devices but does not connect. Once I reboot, i can again connect to WiFi but any transition in the WiFi network, fails to connect to any network available and I have to restart again.

I have been facing a lot of WiFi problems since I use ubuntu 18.04. I really need a fix this time so that this issue doesn't occur again and again.
Here's the link to my previous question:[Cannot connect to Wi-Fi Ubuntu 18.04 (Secure boot disabled)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183252/cannot-connect-to-wi-fi-ubuntu-18-04-secure-boot-disabled)

It's been a long time and I am facing a lot of problem. Please help!

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Summoning Pilot6 or chili555.....

Comment: @chilli555 Please help.